# converting symbols to strings without evaluation

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

How can I make `toStr[list]` that takes a list of symbols and returns them as strings? I'd like `a=1;toStr[{a}]` to give `{"a"}`

**Update 03/02**: Leo's recipe works, also to make a version which takes a sequence instead of list I did `SetAttribute[toStr2,HoldAll];toStr2[a__]:=toStr[{a}]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `HoldForm`:

```
a = 1; b = 2;ToString@HoldForm[{a, b}]
```

This gives `{a, b}`.  To make it into `toStr` function, you need to set the attributes so that it doesn't evaluate the arguments:

```
ClearAll[toStr]; SetAttributes[toStr, {HoldAll, Listable}];
toStr[x_] := ToString@HoldForm[x];
a = 1; b = 2; toStr[{a, b}]
```

Alternatively, you could use `Unevaluated`; in the above code `toStr[x_] := ToString@Unevaluated[x]` would work just as well.

Comment: That gives `"{a,b}"` instead of `{"a","b"}`

Comment: So it does.  Looks like you can change this by setting `Listable` attribute as well (answer edited)

Comment: You could also use `SymbolName` to extract the unqualified symbol name (and `Context` to get the context).